# Lightning Web Components Playground error: An attempt was made to break through the security policy of the user agent

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, error-messages

I'm currently receiving an error when attempting to use the Lightning Mini Playground or the Playground located here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground

The error is: 'SecurityError
An attempt was made to break through the security policy of the user agent.'

It shows the instant I make any change, regardless of the change made (e.g. adding a space). I'm using Chrome browser and I've tried running with no extensions, I'm still get the same error.

Thanks for any and all assistance.

Comment: Can you share the code you are trying to run in playground? @Aidan

Comment: As mentioned in the OP, it occurs regardless of the code inserted. Whether I'm working from a blank page or using the examples in the playground itself, even just changing a label it'll return the error instantly. Using https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-card/example as an example, if I modify anything, the error returns.

Comment: Looks to be an issue with Chrome - I've tried in Firefox and it seems to work.

Comment: OK...nice @Aidan

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me on Chrome by doing the following.
Open up your playground on chrome.
On the URL bar, on the right side, next to the bookmark star button, click the cookies icon, and then click "Show cookies and other site data...".

Go to the "Blocked" tab and allow any of the following domains:

1. salesforce.com
2. developer.salesforce.com
3. ***.cloudfront.net (some plugin from AWS that the site is probably using, this one is often automatically blocked).

Click Done. Refresh your page.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, banging my head for last 20 mins. The answer is given by Aidan. Use firefox.

```
Looks to be an issue with Chrome - I've tried in Firefox and it seems to work. – Aidan
```

Thanks @Aidan